# How can I make the player teleport a certain amount of blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a sort of elevator in Minecraft with a command block. You step into a small room, press the button and get sent a few blocks up to a room above the current room.

[image: The first room and the second room]

Is there a way to send the player a few blocks up or down?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a simple `/tp` command, you either use absolute values, to teleport the player to `100 64 100` you would use this:

```
/tp @p 100 64 100
```

Or relative values, for 3 blocks up that would look like this:

```
/tp @p ~ ~3 ~
```

Note that this will teleport the player relative to the command block, to teleport the player relative to the current loaction you would use:

```
/execute at @p run tp @p ~ ~3 ~
```

Answer (score 1):

on the command block in the room down, input the following command:

`/tp @p ~ ~9 ~`

and on the command block in the room up, input the following command:

`/tp @p ~ ~-9 ~`

these two should teleport the nearest player in the same x and z coordinate, but +9 or -9 from the command block's y coordinate from the command block initiating the command (respectively)